# Stuck in BusyBox initramfs while booting Parrot OS 4.7 I don't know what to do

Tags: dual-boot, grub, busybox, initramfs, parrotsec

I installed Parrot OS 4.7 on Dual Boot with Windows 10 and this happens during booting I tried deleting the partition and reinstalling Parrot OS again but still the same issue! As you can see[The image describes the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYfQj.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot into liveusb or livedvd that you used to install parrot OS 4.7.

open terminal and run :

1. `sudo fdisk -l`
2. `sudo mount /dev/sda*  /mnt`

   (replace * with the number that shown with type= linux in "fdisk" results)
3. `cd /`
4. `cd /boot`
5. `ls`
6. `cp /boot/initrd.img-*******-parrot1-amd64  /mnt/boot`

(replace ***** with numbers that shown with initrd.img in "ls" results)

I hope that was a more detailed tutorial.

Comment: Worked thanks for info