# Just Installed Parrot 6.0 and its automatically dropping me into "BusyBox". how do I boot into the operating system?

Tags: debian, busybox, parrotsec

I just installed the new parrot os 6.0 on my 64 bit laptop and i ran it from a usb, installed it and i get to the grub screen. it automatically boots the first option and then is has the cool new loading screen. then it all stops and spits me right into busybox and i have no why it put me here. please help.

Comment: If your error message looks similar to the one in https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYfQj.jpg (it shows a screenshot from the mentioned question "Stuck in BusyBox initramfs while booting Parrot OS 4.7") , than you could try the solution posted in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/530453/stuck-in-busybox-initramfs-while-booting-parrot-os-4-7-i-dont-know-what-to-do. If your error is different, please provide a bit more information about it.